# AngularJS config causes error when minified

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `.config` code:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(JSONInterceptor);
}]);
```

`JSONInterceptor` is just a simple function:

```
function JSONInterceptor($q, localStorageService) {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            const url = config.url;
            // ignore template requests
            if (url.includes('.html')) {
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
            if (localStorageService.get('use-json-server')) {
                config.url = API_URL + config.url;
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that when I run the app in its non-minified form, everything works as expected. However, when I minify the app, I get an error for a seemingly unrelated service (though I guess they are related in the sense that they both touch `$http`):

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- $http <- $uiRouter
```

I assume that this error has something to do with using a non-angular function as the interceptor (i.e., it is not a `.provider` or a `.factory` etc.), but I am not sure, and my attempts to make `JSONInterceptor` a provider have failed thus far. I know that `.config` has restrictions as to what can be included. However, even if this is the issue, I am having trouble understanding why it works unminified - I would assume that the same restrictions would apply to minified and unminified code.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the minification of the `JSONInterceptor` function. Perhaps `$q` is being minified to `e` and then Angular no longer knows how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the issue happens because of the dependencies injected in the interceptor (`$q, localStorageService`) as they are missing [annotations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation).

To resolve this issue, try to register the interceptor as a factory as follows:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', '$provide', function($httpProvider, $provide) {

  $provide.factory('JSONInterceptor', ['$q', 'localStorageService', function ($q, localStorageService) {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        const url = config.url;
        // ignore template requests
        if (url.includes('.html')) {
          return config || $q.when(config);
        }
        if (localStorageService.get('use-json-server')) {
          config.url = API_URL + config.url;
        }
        return config || $q.when(config);
      }
    };
  }]);

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('JSONInterceptor');
}]);
```